# How to make a h3 tag occupy less space within a div?

Tags: html, css, html-heading

Here is the HTML code:

```
    <div id="homepage_boxes_holder">
        <div class="homepage_boxes">
            <h3 class="box_heading">Test</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="homepage_boxes">
            <h3 class="box_heading">Test</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="homepage_boxes">
            <h3 class="box_heading">Test</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.homepage_boxes{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    line-height: 10;
}

.box_heading{
    text-align:center;
    font-family: BebasNeue;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

For some reason, the h3 is occupying a huge amount of space in the div (it looks as though the padding is huge to me but that can't be since I have set it to 0). I have put a border on the `.box_heading` for demonstrative purposes. Image is here:

Link to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/65R0s.jpg 
 -The blue is the div border, and the black is the H3 border.

EDIT: If possible, I would also like the heading to be centred on the div, rather than pushing outside the boundaries.

Comment: `line-height: 10;` is what's causing it just take it away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you added a `line-height: 10;` to the parent element, which increases the height of each line **10 times**.

Just remove that And it works.

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/B7ZTw/1/)**

### Update

To keep the `h3` element at the middle of its parent, you could set a `line-height` as the parent's `height` to that element (in this case you could apply this CSS declaration to both *parent* and *h3* element).

```css
.homepage_boxes {
    /* ... */
    line-height: 200px;  /* as the same of the parent's height */
}
```

**[Udpated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/B7ZTw/3/)**

Another option is setting the same `padding` to the top and bottom of the *parent* element without setting a fixed `height`, which makes the *children* at the middle.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/B7ZTw/4/)**

Comment: Thank you I see that now. However the reason I added the line height was to try and have the h3 in the centre of the div, do you know how to do that without causing what I caused in the original post?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to the h3:

```
line-height: 1em;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B7ZTw/

---

To center the text both ways please add the following to h3:

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -0.5em;
```

What you do here is: set the h3 to be 50% from the top (so the middle), but then substract half of the element height so it doesn't start at 50% but is centered there.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/B7ZTw/2/

Comment: Thanks! This seems halfway there, problem is that I want the text to be in the centre of the Div, but not push itself outside of the div boundaries. Is that possible?

Comment: @k4kuz0 Just for your information: your chosen answer does not work without problems if you want to keep the 200px height and add text after the h3. Example just in case you need it: http://jsfiddle.net/B7ZTw/5/

Answer (score 0):

just add line-height: 1em; to the .box-heading class description. 
The line-height attribute alters the 'ascent' or 'ascender height' of the font, making it that high.

Answer (score -1):

You can put static height for  if it possible